# Modify a List Inside of a Struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I have been working on a project for my c# class at school.  And I have a very simple question I think.  But I have been unable to find an answer anywhere.  I keep getting results about how to make a list of structs. I want to know how to access a list inside a struct?

So here is the struct given to us by our teacher and that we **must** use for this assignment:

```
[Serializable]
struct Name
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}

[Serializable]
struct Movie
{
    public string title;
    public string year;
    public Name director;
    public float quality;
    public string mpaaRating;
    public string genre;
    public List<Name> cast;
    public List<string> quotes;
    public List<string> keywords;
}

struct MovieList
{
    public int length;
    public Movie[] movie;
}
```

Now I have tried accessing quotes and keywords in the following two ways and both have produced errors:

1.

```
string quotes;
MovieList ML = new MovieList();

quotes = Console.ReadLine();
ML.movie[0].quotes[0] = quotes;
```

2.

```
string quotes;
MovieList ML = new MovieList();

quotes = Console.ReadLine();
ML.movie[0].quotes.Add(quotes);
```

Comment: You don't want Movie to be a struct. Make it a class. For more, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx).

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, do you mean you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A struct is a `Value` type and as such, using a struct to carry all of this information makes it very inefficient because every time you pass it as an argument the whole contents of the struct will need to be copied, etc. a better approach would be to use a Class, which is a `Reference` type and it's reference is what gets passed around.

As far as how to access your struct members, here's an example:

```
MovieList m =new MovieList();
m.movie = new Movie[10];
m.movie[0].title="The Girl with the Dragon Tatoo";
Console.WriteLine(m.movie[0].title); //The Girl with the Dragon Tatoo
```

**UPDATE:**

Showing how to access quotes:

```
MovieList m =new MovieList();
m.movie = new Movie[10];
m.movie[0].title="The Girl with the Dragon Tatoo";
m.movie[0].quotes = new List<string>();
m.movie[0].quotes.Add("Hello World");
Console.WriteLine(m.movie[0].title); //The Girl with the Dragon Tatoo

Console.WriteLine(m.movie[0].quotes[0]); //Hello World
```

Comment: Yes thank you Icarus I have been able to read and write with the the title though.  My problem is I need to know to access quotes and keywords.  And I would have used a class if our teacher did not require the structs.   Quotes and Keywords are the two fields I get errors from when I try to read and write from them.

Comment: If you were here I would hug you Icarus.  Thanks a bunch.  This is my first time using c#'s built in list class and I was not familiar with that.  I really appreciate it. :D

Comment: A constructor to new up the Lists/array would ease the use of these structs considarably.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MovieList` struct contains an array of `Movie`. The array isn't being initialized.

Why not just make a `List<Movie>` instead of a separate struct or class?

Comment: I didn't put in all the code because it's a large assignment but I have initialized the array. `ML.movie = new Movie[MAX_MOVIES];`
I have been able to input and output from everything but quotes and keywords.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for being honest about your homework. The first problem I see is that you are trying to use the list before they are initialized. Inside the structures, brand-new list are referencing to null. You have to initialize them. Please do a research about struct initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Make these classes rather than structs. For every Movie in your MovieList class you will have to create a new instance of Movie so you can add to the quotes list. Otherwise it wont be initialised.

Comment: Thanks for the quick input.  It has to be in a struct for this assignment.  Our teacher gave us the part about the structs and he will be grading us based off of this.  Isn't there any way?

Comment: Okay sure. Just initalise the Movie array object and create a new instance of the quotes list.

Answer (score 0):

Structures should generally avoid exposing fields or properties of mutable class types, except in cases where the struct will be used by code which is merely interested in the *identity* of the objects referred to therein, rather than their *content*.  Suppose one has structures `m1`, which contains information about some movie, and `m2`, which is initially blank.  If one executes code:

```
  m2 = m1;
  m2.year = 2012;
  m2.keywords.Add("dinosaur")
```

Then `m1.year` will be unmodified, but `m1.keywords` will have "dinosaur" added to it (since `m1.keywords` and `m2.keywords` both refer to the same mutable `List<string>`.

It's fine for structs which are used as data-holders to expose read-write fields of logically-immutable class types, or value types which don't contain any mutable class types, but structs which hold mutable reference types often have weird semantics and should be avoided when practical.